# "export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc

[Error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ujY.png)

[Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqx70.png)

send help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.